# (1) $a+b+c=1$. (2) $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=0$. how to calculate the $\frac{b}{a}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The Question is the if we can deduce the $\frac{b}{a}$ is definite value  according to the two conditions

Two Known conditions ：a,b, and c are non-zero real numbers(1) $a+b+c=1$.
(2) $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=0$.

I choose wrong,but the answer at the back of the book is right

Here are my process

$\begin{aligned} (1) \Rightarrow & a+b=1-c \\ a b c \cdot (2) \Rightarrow & b c+a c+a b=0 \\ & \Rightarrow a b+(a+b) c=0 \\ & \quad a b+(a+b)[1-(a+b)]=0 \\ &  \quad a^{2}+a b+b^{2}=a+b \end{aligned}$

I don't know what to do next,I'm trying to use a binary first order equation with a as the pivot.Doesn't seem to work.

I also tried replacing all of the 1 in equation (2) with equation (1).

I've tried a few other things, but the results are pretty much the same. So I think my answer is right

so I can't seem to solve for definite value.

so please!
How do you solve for a definite value if you can solve for it.

This is my first time asking questions. If you have any suggestions, I'm all ears!

Comment: is $(a,b,c)>0$ ?

Comment: @KeshavSingh : Can't be.  Contradicts (2).

Comment: You want to know what $b/a$ is. So, let $b/a=x$. So, $b=ax$. Now use that to eliminate $b$ from the last equation you wrote down. See what happens. Anyway, what's the answer at the back of the book?

Comment: Correct me if I'm missing something, but there can't be a unique number defined by these equations, due to the symmetry of the equations. Since we can swap the roles of $a$ and $c$, then we would have to have $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{b} \implies a = c$. Similar argument shows $b = c$. But this is inconsistent with (1) and (2).

Comment: @Theo Bendit: i I know what you mean.actually I suspect I got the answer wrong at the back of the book

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: the answer is right,i don't know why,actually I suspect  the answer  at the back of the book

Comment: @ Keshav Singh just a,b, and c are non-zero real numbers

Comment: To give concrete support to Theo Bendit's comment, if you choose $a = \frac 12$, your equation solves to $b = \frac {1 \pm \sqrt 5}4$, which gives $c = \frac {1\mp \sqrt 5}4$. You can confirm that both equations (1) and (2) are satisfied, but there are two values for $\frac ba$. Further, $a$ was chosen arbitrarily and $b$ does not depend linearly on it. $a$ can be choosen from a range, and will give $b$ values with different valid $\frac ba$ ratios.

Comment: Rewrite as $$\begin{cases}a+b&=1-c\\ab&=-c(a+b)=c(c-1)\end{cases}$$ and you have a simple sum/product problem where $c$ is a free parameter.

Answer (score -2):

since we look in to Real solutions, to make it more clear lets consider reduced version of the same question without reducing number of variables and a, b, c labels replaced with x, y, z

$ x + y + z = 1   $  ---------(1)

$1/x + 1/y + 1/z= 0 $ ----------(2)

from $(1)^2$ and $(2)*xyz$ we can easily derive

$ x^2 + y^2 + z^2= 1 $ -----------(3)

(3) is a sphere originated at (0, 0, 0) with a radius of unit 1.

this tells

$ 1 ≥ x^2 > 0 $  ;  $ 1 ≥  y^2 > 0 $  ; $ 1 ≥  z^2 > 0 $

for an instance if we take k where $ 1 ≥  k ≥ 0  $ and of  $ z^2 = k $   then rest of the equation becomes

$ x^2 + y ^2 = 1-k $ ---------(4)

(4) is a circle with radius of units $ (1-k) $ originated in (0, 0). in other words a slice from the sphere described in (3). actually there are more than 1 slice that fits the condition.

now lets bring the idea of having $ b/a $ to be definitive in this format. means $ y/x $ to be definitive.

$ y / x  = m $ ------------(5) here m is a Real scaler

that makes $ y = m*x $ a line goes through (0, 0) origin.
but we know its not a line its a circle in the same origin. so answer is, its not a definitive value. answer is its a Real equation.

Comment: $x, y, z$ cannot be zero. Contradicts (2).

Comment: yes, that only removing axis points, for the general idea im trying to explain will stay. i will update it thanks